# Password Protect for fun

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a blog for my friend. I want to gift him the blog on his birthday.

Just for some fun I want to restrict access to the blog. e.g.

The website.

www.myfriend.com opens with a splash screen. The screen has his picture and a question regarding him.

these questions can be.
If you know me....
What is my nickname?

Whats my fav. sport?

etc etc

This restriction should not be based on the default user management offered by Wordpress>  and should involve a simple answer to a question which is randomly generated from list of questions> once the visitor gives a correct answer the page redirects to the blog.
Please note even if the user types www.myfriend.com/blog they should be able to see it.

this restriction is not a restriction in true sense but just involves some user interaction.

Its just for fun but adds a bit of `spice`.

Much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

YOu could use javascript with a cookie.

If they don't have the cookie set, have the javascript send them to a page where a security cookie is set (ie your question page), and then once they have they cookie set, direct them back to the main blog page.  Not secure by any means, which I don't think you care too much about, but it should be quick and easy.

Comment: Hi Zoidberg,

Thanks for your reply. But I don't know how to implement it to be honest. 

I don't either know JS or PHP properly.

From my understanding, I think the solution should be simpler.

Comment: Hmmm, so your looking for an out of the box solution... not sure of any out of box solutions that would support this action... but hey, maybe its a good idea for one of us geeks to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Lock a Blog](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/lockablog/) plugin, but modify it. Give it a try!